# How to adjust screen size for all android devices

Tags: android-layout, android-xml, android-screen-support

I just can't seem to find a way to fit the photo onto my home page screen, I've tried many different ways but it wasn't successful. I have an image that pushes the layout that is under it and squeezes the buttons on the screen. Is there any way I can auto resize the height it for different screens? I only need the height since the width should be match_parent. Below is the xml file.

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
   >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/nav_bar_homepage" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pageTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="WELCOME!" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/hiddenIcDrawer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/nav_icon"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/horLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/line_big_white" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_homepage_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/image_homepage"
             />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/field_red_homepage"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo_homep"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_homepage" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/redeembytton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_redeemrewards"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/orderbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_orderonline"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rewardsButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_earnrewards"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/referFriendButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_referafriend"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" >
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap you xml code into **ScrollView** if you are okay with scrolling down to reach your contents under ImageView. If you don't want to scroll down, it is best to use "weight" attribute. I am giving you an idea how to implement it in your code.

Let's say the height of the whole screen is 1. You have an image and a button to put on the screen for all devices. So split the screen into two parts... 0.8 for imageview and 0.2 for the button. You can use the code below to get this result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"  <!-- Important >
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight=".8" > <!-- 80% of your screen size>

        <!-- Your ImageView >

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"  <!-- Important >
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight=".2" > <!-- 20% of your screen size>

        <!-- Your Button >

     </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you that helped :D, I went with the weight option since scrollview was not allowed on the home page

Answer (score 0):

Try this

I think you should use 
*`android:layout-weight="1"`* for adjusting the height according to different devices.use it in your *`<ImageLayout/>`*.